# Rendering views block values in a custom form field

Tags: views, 8, forms, blocks, hooks

I want a select list in a custom form drop down field which should list down all node titles specific to a content type. For this, I have created a view block, restricted it to one content type, allowing only node titles in its fields, and I am rendering this in the custom form. Below is the code I am using to do this:

In custom module:

```
$customblock = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('community_list', []);
$variables['content']['community_select_list'] = $customblock->build();

$form['community'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Community name'),
  '#options' => array(
    $variables['content']['community_select_list'],
  ),
);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try looping the values.

Comment: or use `'#type' => 'entity_autocomplete'`